# Spring Boot,Spring application gets connection refused when trying to connect to elasticsearch in GKE

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have successfully deployed elasticsearch at gke following the steps of [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html#k8s-deploy-elasticsearch) tutorial

The problem appears when applying the deployment descriptor of my application where it gets the following exception when trying to connect to elasticserach:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:100) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doExists(IndicesTemplate.java:170) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.exists(IndicesTemplate.java:162) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:83) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:210) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar!/:6.0.3]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:930) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.3.jar!/:8.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.3.jar!/:8.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-8.5.3.jar!/:8.5.3]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.3.jar!/:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.ElasticsearchIndicesClient.exists(ElasticsearchIndicesClient.java:620) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(IndicesTemplate.java:170) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:71) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar!/:5.0.0]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.16.jar!/:4.4.16]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.5.jar!/:4.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]"
```

the application properties are the following:

```
spring.elasticsearch.uris=https://localhost:9200
spring.elasticsearch.connection-timeout=1s
spring.elasticsearch.socket-timeout=1m
spring.elasticsearch.username=elastic
spring.elasticsearch.password=the_password
```

and the elasticsearch configuration class is the following:

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = {"my.app.search.repositories"})
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
}
```

thank you in advance for your time

Comment: "spring.elasticsearch.uris=https://localhost:9200" I doubt, that when you deployed Elasticsearch in GKE, that is is running on the same machine as your Spring Boot application, so configuring "localhost:9200" very certainly is not correct.

Comment: Where is the Springboot app running ?

Comment: replace localhost:9200 with elasticsearch:9200